# Поиск по базе данных не работает, если искать на русском

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Если ввожу данные на английском, то получаю удовлетворительный ответ
при вводе русских букв получаю перечень всех столбцов, а не искомое значение
У name формат cp1251_general_ci

Адрес, на котором реализовываю этот код
http://royality.xyz/phptest3/index.php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or die("could not connect");
    mysql_select_db("base") or die("could not find db!");
    mysql_query ("set_client='utf8'");
    mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
    mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
    mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
    $output = '';

    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM medical WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%' ") or die ("could not search");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($count == 0){
            $output = 'There was no search results!';
        }else{
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $name = $row['name'];
                $manufacturer = $row['manufacturer'];
                $id = $row['id'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                $output .= '<div>'. $name .' '. $manufacturer.' '. $description.'</div>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search for members..." onkeydown="searchq();" />
            <input type="submit" value=">>" />
        </form>
        <?php
            print("$output");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: кодировка в поле `name` какая?

Comment: меня больше инрересует где вы нарыли mysql_connect? никто не пользуется уже этим. На худой конец есть - mysqli_connect

Comment: В name кодировка cp1251_general_ci

Comment: поменяйте на utf8_general_ci

Comment: Ничего не изменилось(